# Detect console window?

Tags: .net, console

Is it possible to detect if an application has an console window? Either by have used AllocConsole or if it's a regular console application.

**Edit:**

Solution (thanks to ho1's answer):

```
public static class ConsoleDetector
{
    private const uint ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = 0x0ffffffff;
    private const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5;
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(uint dwProcessId);
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool FreeConsole();


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets if the current process has a console window.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool HasOne
    {
        get
        {
            if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
            {
                FreeConsole();
                return false;
            }

            //If the calling process is already attached to a console, 
            // the error code returned is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
            return Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say console window are you referring to a console application or simply a window?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? First of all I mentioned the AllocConsole method and then wrote "console application" in my question. Finally ho1 gave an answer mentioning AttachConsole :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably some neater way of doing it but I suppose you could call [AttachConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and check if it fails with `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` (which it will if the process has no console) or not.